# List vs Dict and using Zip: list(zip) works fine but dict(zip) is a little off

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Using python 3, I have the Morse code list of string assigned to variable values:

```
values = [".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."]
```

I also have the alphabet in string format that is converted to list and assigned to keys:

```
keys = list('abcdebghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

now I am using the zip() to combine both together and assign it to my_dict

```
my_dict =zip(keys,values)
```

if I convert my_dict to list :

```
my_dict = list (my_dict)

print (my_dict)
```

I get this output:

```
[('a', '.-'), **('b', '-...'),** ('c', '-.-.'), ('d', '-..'), ('e', '.'), ('b', '..-.'), ('g', '--.'), ('h', '....'), ('i', '..'), ('g', '.---'), ('k', '-.-'), ('l', '.-..'), ('m', '--'), ('n', '-.'), ('o', '---'), ('p', '.--.'), ('q', '--.-'), ('r', '.-.'), ('s', '...'), ('t', '-'), ('u', '..-'), ('v', '...-'), ('w', '.--'), ('x', '-..-'), ('y', '-.--'), ('z', '--..')]
```

Which is what I expect, each index is a combo of the prior two lists.

However when I convert `my_dict` to dictionary and print:

```
my_dict = dict(my_dict)

print (my_dict)
```

I get this output(sorry cant seem to post properly):

```
{'y': '-.--', 'c': '-.-.', 'o': '---', 'r': '.-.', 'a': '.-', 't': '-', 'g': '.---', 'v': '...-', 'z': '--..', 'e': '.', 'w': '.--', 'n': '-.', 'i': '..', 'l': '.-..', 'h': '....', 'q': '--.-', 'm': '--', 's': '...', 'p': '.--.', 'x': '-..-', 'k': '-.-', 'u': '..-', 'd': '-..', **'b': '..-.'**}
```

My question is... I know that dictionary is unordered. but why is the value of 'b' different:
the first output prints this ('b', '-...') which is correct and I understand
the second output prints this 'b': '..-.' which makes no sense.

'a' 'c' 'd' and others seem to be fine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alphabet has 2 b's:

```
keys = list('abcdebghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
              ^   ^
--------------|---|
```

Therefore, when you create your dictionary, the second mapping will overwrite the first. Moreover, your dictionary will not have an `f` key. Note also that you have 2 g's and `j` missing.

Instead, you can use `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

print(ascii_lowercase)

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: O my gosh. I feel like a complete idiot . I was so focused on one part of the problem that I completely missed to check the alphabet. Much appreciated jpp.